# Tmux shared window: close in only one session

Tags: tmux

Imagine a window `W` is shared between sessions `S1` and `S2` (e.g. created in `S1` and then joined into `S2`).

I want to close it only in `S2`, so that it remains in `S1` -- is there a way to do that? Current behavior: if I close it in `S2`, it gets killed in `S1` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html):

> Sessions in the same group share **the same set of windows** - new windows are linked to all sessions in the group and **any windows closed removed from all sessions**.

You can move the window to another session (say `S3`) with `move-window`.